# Word-splitting when parameter is used within command substitution

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, command-substitution

What needs to be done to ensure that a parameter containing embedded spaces is handled correctly when used within a command substitution? Perhaps an example will illustrate

```
$ file="/home/1_cr/xy z"
$ basename $file
xy

$ #need to pass basename a quoted $file to prevent the z in 'xy z' from being eaten
$ basename "$file"
xy z

$ #Now using $file inside a command substitution without quoting.....
$ #....the command substitution causes 'xy z' to split
$ set -- $(basename "$file")
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
xy
z

$ #But quoting the command substitution does not prevent 'xy z'...... 
$ #....from being split before being passed to basename
$ set -- "$(basename $file)"
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
xy
```

What do i need to do so that

```
$ set -- $(basename $file)
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

yields

```
xy z
```

Comment: `set -- "$(basename "$file")"`? At least this works on my system.

Comment: @JosephR. lol...and I thought i would have to do something a lot more complicated. Do you know how the word-splitting plays out with your solution?

Comment: The internal quotes simply protect `$file` from word expansion when passed to `basename` as in your own example. Just because you quoted the command substitution doesn't mean everything inside it is immune to word expansion.

Comment: @JosephR. thanks! See my comment against Gilles answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put double quotes around all variable and command substitutions.

```
set -- "$(basename -- "$file")"
```

If you allow the value of the variable to be split into words and these words to be treated as glob patterns, there's no going back. You can no longer tell how much whitespace was there or whether the file names were the result of a wildcard expansion. You can't turn the hamburger back into a cow, so you must make sure not to send the cow to the abattoir in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. What threw me off was the difference in the way bash handles nested double-quotes in `set -- "xy "$file""` versus `set -- "$(basename -- "$file")"`. So when command substitution comes into play, bash is able to interpret nested quotes "naturally"?

Comment: @1_CR Yes (provided you use the `$(…)` form of command substitution, and not the obsolescent backquotes).

Answer (score 3):

You have several options,

1. Use *"$*"* instead *"$@"*

   ```
    set -- $(basename "$file")
    printf "%s\n" "$*"
   ```
2. Quote the command substitution and the variable,

   ```
    set -- "$(basename "$file")"
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
   ```

Comment: Really shouldn't use #1 as it can still produce unreliable results. #2 is only way :-)